# Why is `man` outputing to stdout instead of $PAGER (less)?

Tags: man, less, pager

When I run `man [program]`, the man page text is output on the terminal (a la `cat`, without a pager that provides interactivity) instead of opening the man page file in `less` (so you can scroll, search, etc.):

```
➜ man git commit
GIT-COMMIT(1)                   Git Manual                  GIT-COMMIT(1)

NAME
       git-commit - Record changes to the repository

SYNOPSIS
[...the rest of the man page]
```

I've verified that `echo $PAGER` returns `less`. Running `man -D -P less [program]` still outputs to the terminal "like `cat` does", without providing the ability to scroll or search etc., like `less` usually does.

Using the debug flag `-d`, `man` says "`using /usr/bin/less as pager`". I'm at a loss for what is happening.

Other useful information:

```
➜ env | grep LESS       
LESS=-R -M
LESS_TERMCAP_mb=
LESS_TERMCAP_md=
LESS_TERMCAP_me=
LESS_TERMCAP_so=
LESS_TERMCAP_se=
LESS_TERMCAP_us=
LESS_TERMCAP_ue=
➜ echo $TERM     
xterm-256color
```

I do get an error for only one program. I don't believe it is directly relevant, but see [this GH issue](https://github.com/Jguer/yay/issues/1157) for details on that. tl;dr, the error that appears is `troff: <standard input>:1: name expected (got '\ '): treated as missing`

This is also cross posted to the [Manjaro forums here.](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/why-is-man-outputing-to-stdout-instead-of-pager-less/119965)

### Update:

Issue is with [zpm-zsh/colorize](https://github.com/zpm-zsh/colorize). I thought doing `\man` would ignore the function, but `\` only ignores aliases. Removing this plugin solves the issue, but I'd like to understand why.

Comment: _How do you know_, especially in the face of the debug output saying otherwise, and the fact that `less` writes to standard output, that `less` is not involved here?  [Use the standard litany](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html).  What _exactly_ did the computer do?  How _exactly_ is that not as expected?  "It used standard output." is _not_ exact.

Comment: @JdeBP Updated. I thought I followed the standard litany, but maybe I don't fully understand stdout and that's where the issue was(?).

Comment: You _still_ aren't describing anything that `less` does not do.  `less` "outputs on the terminal" too, in the way shown.  Describe _exactly_ the thing that makes you think that this is not the `less` program in action.

Comment: @JdeBP I guess I've reached the limits of my linux understanding/terminology. I've updated the post with what I guess you're asking for. 

I posted the exact output from my terminal, and even mentioned that it essentially behaves like `cat`. Is there a term for the area underneath the shell prompt that isn't stdout?

Comment: Any idea which amount of lines is reported for the terminal? If somehow one of the involved applications or libraries takes it is in the thousands, you would indeed end up with a result like this. Same thing happens with annoying javascript turning off scrollbars (the whole function), but I suppose now you see the bottom part only as the whole page is output at once (as assumed to fit all on screen).

Comment: Result of `echo "$TERM"` and the number of columns and lines reported by `stty -a` please.

Comment: @roaima I've updated the question with `$TERM`, but my computer does not have `ssty`.

Comment: `stty` please. Not `ssty`

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was running was a namespace matching issue with `env`.

oh-my-zsh's [colored-man-pages](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/colored-man-pages) uses `env` when setting up variables:

```bsh
function colored() {
    env \
        LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(printf "\e[1;31m") \
        LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(printf "\e[1;31m") \
        LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(printf "\e[0m") \
        LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(printf "\e[0m") \
        LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(printf "\e[1;44;33m") \
        LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(printf "\e[0m") \
        LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(printf "\e[1;32m") \
        PAGER="${commands[less]:-$PAGER}" \
        _NROFF_U=1 \
        PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" \
            "$@"
}

function man() {
    colored man "$@"
}
```

I also use another plugin, [zpm-zsh/colorize](https://github.com/zpm-zsh/colorize) which routes `env` through `grv` ([general colourizer](https://github.com/garabik/grc)) through as a separate function called `env`:

```bsh
function env () {
    =grc --colour=auto env "$@"
}
```

For whatever reason, `grc` does something that `man` doesn't like.

### Solution:

#### 1) Don't redefine `env` through `grc` using a globally defined function

#### 2) Ensure that `env` is not an alias/function by using `command`

```bsh
function colored() {
    command env \
        LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(printf "\e[1;31m") \
[....]
}

function man() {
    colored man "$@"
}
```